# Holomorphic semigroup can be extended to a strongly continous semigroup on $L^{p}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I have a question about $C_{0}$-semigroup theory.

Let $(H,(\, , \,))$ be a real Hilber space and $(H_{\mathbb{C}}, (\, , \,))$ the its complexification. Any linear operator $(L,D(L))$ on $H$ can be extended to an operator $(L^{\mathbb{C}},D(L^{\mathbb{C}}))$ on $H_{\mathbb{C}}$ by

$L^{\mathbb{C}}([u,v])=[Lu,Lv]$ for $[u,v] \in D(L^{\mathbb{C}}):=\{[u,v] \in H^{\mathbb{C}}: u,v \in D(L) \}$.

Define for $K \in (0,\infty)$, $S(K)=\left\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |\text{Im} z| \le K \text{Re}z\right\}$.

**Definition**

Let $K \in (0, \infty)$. A family $(T_{z})_{z \in S(K)}$ of bounded linear operators on $H_{\mathbb{C}}$ is called a holomorphic contraction semigroup 
on $S(K)$ if

1. $T_{0}=id_{H_{\mathbb{C}}}$.
2. $T_{z_{1}+z_{2}}=T_{z_{1}}T_{z_{2}}$ for all $z_{1},z_{2} \in S(K)$.
3. $T_{z}f \to f$ in $H_{\mathbb{C}}$ as $z \to 0$ in $S(\tilde{K})$ for all $f \in H_{\mathbb{C}}$ and all $\tilde{K}<K$.
4. $\|T_{z}\| \leq 1$ for all $z \in S(K)$.
5. $z \to (T_{z}f,g)$ is analytic on the interior of $S(K)$ for all $f,g$ in $H_{\mathbb{C}}$.

> **My question**
>
> Let $(X,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(T_{t})$ be a
>   strongly continuous contraction semigroup on $L^{2}(X;\mu)$. Suppose
>   that $(e^{-t}T_{t}^{\mathbb{C}})_{t>0}$ is the restriction of a
>   holomorphic contraction semigroup on the sector $S(K^{-1})$ for some
>   $K \in (0,\infty)$. Then can we find $q_{0}>2$ such that $(T_{t})$ has
>   a strongly continous extention on $L^{p}(X;\mu)$ for any $p \in
>  [2,q_{0}]$?

**My researh**

If $(T_{t})_{t>0}$ satisfies the Markovian property, we can find such extension on $L^{p}(X;\mu)$ for any $p \in [2,\infty)$...

If you know, please let me know!

Thank you in advance.